# Anchor case definition in recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, anchor

Anchor case definition is as follows:

> The value of the function is specified for one or more values of the parameter.

Now let's take a look at the recursive factorial function:

```
int fact(int n)
{
   if (n == 0)
      return 1;
   else
      return n * fact(n - 1);
}
```

I understand this bit: "the value of the function is specified..."
I get that; when the function reaches anchor case, it simply returns 1.

What I don't understand is that how the value of the function is "specified for one or more values of the parameter"?

Is the definition talking about the function parameter or the mathematical terms of parameter? I just don't see the value of the function is specified for one or more values of the [function] parameters when the run-time stack gets popped.

Comment: Thia definition looks wrong to me, and I think the base case should be returning 1, otherwise every input will return zero.

Answer (score 0):

Some recursive functions have more than one base case. For instance, The Fibonacci sequence has specified values for inputs `0` and `1`, and recurses for higher values.

```
unsigned int fib(unsigned n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get that. What I really don't understand is.. if, say, fib(n-1) in inductive case gets replaced by 1 after anchor case is reached and becomes "return 1 + fib(n-2)", can we say that the function value was specified for the parameter value? In other words, does "fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)" in inductive case considered to be parameters in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The only parameter is `n`. In the inductive case, you call the function again with different parameters, `n-1` and `n-2`.

Comment: When the textbook says "specified", it means that there's a predefined result for that input, rather than having to compute it using induction.

Answer (score 0):

This refers to functional parameters.  This is a static property of the function; it has nothing to do with transient status at run-time.  "when the run-time stack gets popped" is not an issue.

The concept is that every recursion must move us closer to an answer.  That means that there must be an absolute (not recursive) value at the bottom of the call tree.  That answer is the anchor case.

Some processes will have only one anchor.  Fibonacci has two.  Some have more, depending on where the "bottom" is for that particular process.